# Top Questions of the Week #14

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into post 14 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest).  If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we are going to try to post about the question and it's contents.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I quite like [Is NTFS really secure?](https://superuser.com/questions/278645/is-ntfs-really-secure) as it is something that can confuse someone who is new to dual booting and computer security in general.

Basically a computer is secure *within the confines of the running operating system* and I think that there are probably quite a few people that assume because they have a password to get into Windows then they are secure.

This question points out that it is the prerogative of the operating system to enforce security and almost all operating systems do not cater for the security of "guest" filesystems.  The answers are good in that they point out that the only way to maintain security is to use encryption in one form or another.

People should be aware that all anyone needs in order to completely compromise a system any Linux LiveCD can pretty much see everything you have if you are not using encryption.